# Inserção MySql com com "Ligação" entre inserções

Tags: php, mysql

estou com um problemão aqui.

Preciso fazer um upload de multiplos arquivos e inseri-los em tabelas diferentes.

A tabela produtos contem os detalhes dos produtos e a tabela fotos os arquivos para acessar as imagens, só que preciso relaciona-las de acordo com o ID, como faço para inserir as fotos em outra tabela com o id do produto da primeira tabela?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitProduto'])){

//Caminho para salvar
$caminho = "uploads/";

$produto = trim($_POST["produto"]);
$informacao = trim($_POST["informacao"]);
$categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
$subCategoria = $_POST['subCategoria'];

// Verifica Checkbox
if (isset($_POST['destaque'])) {
    $destaque = 1;
}
else {
    $destaque = 0;
}


//Inseri imagem
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["fotos"]["name"]); $i++) {

    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$i];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][$i];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$i];

    if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {

        $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
        $extensao = end($arquivoArray);

        $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

        move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo);

        // lastInserId
        $last = $database::insert_id();

        $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos (nome,descricao,categoria,destaque, sub_categoria) VALUES ('".$produto."', '".$informacao."','".$categoria."','".$destaque."', '".$subCategoria."')");
        $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos_fotos (id_produto, imagem) VALUES ('".$last."', '".$arquivo."')");

        }
    }

$message = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Produtos cadastrados com sucesso!</div>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Posta o código fonte também

Comment: pronto @rray já adicionei, o que eu quero é inserir os detalhes na tabela produto e que o id_produto da tabela produtos_fotos seja o mesmo.

Comment: Depois do primeiro insert, chama a função [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) ela vai retornar o id do registro inserido, depois pegue ele e grave no segundo insert.

Comment: mysql_inser_id não funciona mais e caso eu use isso ele vai pegar o ultimo id inserido na tabela produtos_fotos e não na tabela produtos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa deixar de fora o primeiro insert, e dentro do for sim colocar o insert das imagens... se não ele vai repetir vários inserts dos produtos.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitProduto'])){

    //Caminho para salvar
    $caminho = "uploads/";

    $produto = trim($_POST["produto"]);
    $informacao = trim($_POST["informacao"]);
    $categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
    $subCategoria = $_POST['subCategoria'];

    // Verifica Checkbox
    if (isset($_POST['destaque'])) {
        $destaque = 1;
    }
    else {
        $destaque = 0;
    }


    //Inseri imagem
    $sqlInsere = $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos (nome,descricao,categoria,destaque, sub_categoria) VALUES ('".$produto."', '".$informacao."','".$categoria."','".$destaque."', '".$subCategoria."')");

    $sqlUltimoID = $database::query("SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 1");
    $rowUltimoID = $database::row($sqlUltimoID);

    // lastInserId
    $last = $rowUltimoID['id'];


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["fotos"]["name"]); $i++) {

        $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$i];
        $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][$i];
        $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$i];

        if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {

            $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
            $extensao = end($arquivoArray);

            $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

                if(move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)){
                    $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos_fotos (id_produto, imagem) VALUES ('".$last."', '".$arquivo."')");
                } else {
                    echo "Não foi possível enviar a imagem";    
                }
        }
    }

$message = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Produtos cadastrados com sucesso!</div>';

}
```